# How to clean saved dockerfiles after build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new at Docker and I'm checking how to build some containers.

After successfully install docker app on my linux server, I've executed the following command:

> docker build -t Dockerfile .

Content of this file:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

#Install.
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install apache2 && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

After some executions I've modified the content of the file and also, the name of the file but it is still executing the same code.

I've done the following steps:

> docker rmi -f

and also:

> docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

But the dockerfile executed is still being executed as it was in the first instance but now it looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN echo "Hola"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Dockerfile` is *"executed"* only by the [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) command.

It interprets the `Dockerfile` and creates (or updates on subsequent runs) an image. The image is used to create the containers.

Think of [`Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) as the source code of your program written in a compiled language (C, C++, Java etc). The image is the executable program stored in a file on disk. The container is the program launched in execution (in memory).

Of course, after you modify the `Dockerfile` you have to run [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) again to update the image then use the image with [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) to launch new containers based on it.

Comment: Thanks axiac, but I've the problem when executing docker build when I've modified the dockerfile, the same errors are displayed despite of the fact that I've removed everything.